# How to force a user to download a file i.e not allowing to save as in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file, pdf

I want to force download a file which is in my stream to the user. I want to save the file on the users disk disallowing the save as functionality as we don't want the user to change the file name while downloading. Here is my code which works fine on the basis of browser setting

```
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf;";
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=abc.pdf");
        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(downloadData[0].data, 0, downloadData[0].data.Length);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(data);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

I know that the

```
Ask where to save each file before downloading
```

is a browser setting. Is there a concrete solution to disable this and force download in each browser?

Comment: The simple answer is no. At least the user can move and/or rename the file after it has been saved. It is also a security feature that prevents this happening.

Comment: Unless you're willing to write your own browser, this isn't possible. When you return the File(StreamResult) - The browser does the rest. Like @PeterSmith said, they can change the name once its' finished downloading. You won't be able to enforce anything.

Comment: Ignoring for a moment that it's not possible, what's the poor user's experience going to be like if your "divinely named" file name happens to be the same as a file they've currently been using to store their accounts in?

Comment: A simple question: why???

Comment: I know that it shouldn't be possible. The client requirement is such so I am forced to think over it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above this is not possible. Once your file goes to the browser it is under the user's control.

One possible option is to use a cookie to store some specific data that you want to use later perhaps for user information/activity. Although, again, this can be blocked by the user it is a more stable approach.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. How does cookie help in overriding the browser setting or force download?
Thanks

Comment: It depends on why you want to have a fixed filename/location. That was also asked by ZorgoZ. Once we know that I can be more specific.